# Woocommerce: Redirect after lost password submitted

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try to redirect my users to a custom page after successfully submitting the lost password form. By default, users are redirected to the "my-account" page.

The method responsible for doing this redirect is called **process_lost_password()** and is located in plugins/woocommerce/includes/**class-wc-form-handler.php** and looks like follows:

```
/**
 * Handle lost password form.
 */
public static function process_lost_password() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wc_reset_password'] ) && isset( $_POST['user_login'] ) && isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'lost_password' ) ) {
        $success = WC_Shortcode_My_Account::retrieve_password();

        // If successful, redirect to my account with query arg set.
        if ( $success ) {
            wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'reset-link-sent', 'true', wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'lost-password' ) ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this method does not offer any action to hook into.

Is there a way to override this method or change the redirect link in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since process_lost_password() is run as an 'wp_load' action

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', array( __CLASS__, 'process_lost_password' ), 20 );
```

You simply need to add your own action with a higher priority

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'your_handler', 19 );
```

Answer (score -1):

I RESOLVED the issue by going under
WooCommerce
Emails****
Place your email in the box all the way to the bottom where it states From address because I am the administrator and Remove the admin email address.

I did a couple of dummy accounts and it work fine now all passwords work very well.

I created a page added the end points to /lost-password/ for my permalinks. Checked the custom header and checked the title boxes towards the middle of page and Published the page. That fixed the issue for me.